# Prove that $\{T(x),T^2(x),\dots,T^{n-1}(x)\}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Question :

Assume that $V$ is a vector space with dimension $n-1$ and $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation.

If for one $x \in V$ :  $T^{n-1}(x) \neq 0$ but $T^n(x)=0$ , Prove that $\{T(x),T^2(x),\dots,T^{n-1}(x)\}$ is linearly independent. ( So it's a basis of $V$ ) .  Find Matrix respresntation of $T$ with respect to this basis.

My work so far :

Assume that there exists a linear combination like $\alpha_1T(x)+\alpha_2T^2(x)+\dots+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(x)=0$.
I want to prove that $\forall i\space\space\alpha_i=0$.  I must prove that none of $T^i(x) : i \le{n-1}$ are zero.  I have no idea how to show that ...

Comment: You have an $n$ dimensional vector space and the set you are trying to prove as the basis contains only $n-1$ elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_1T(x)+...+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(x)=0$ implies that $T^{n-2}(a_1T(x)+...+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(x))=a_1T^{n-1}(x)=0$ implies $a_1=0$, end recursively: suppose $a_1=..=a_i=0$, $T^{n-i-2}(a_{i+1}T^{i+1}(x)+...+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(x)))=a_{i+1}T^{n-1}(x))=0$ implies that $a_{i+1}=0$.

Comment: No idea about matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis ?